# Wordpress: insert a custom post type instance as an option for a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, one-to-many, custom-post-type

I'm trying to connect a custom post type to a taxonomy defined in an other custom post type.

I'll show you an example. I have a custom post type COURSE, i use this post type to create a class for a university, so in this post type i'll have some custom field (teacher, lesson schedule ecc ecc) and a taxonomy called Teacher.

Teacher is an other custom post type i use to represent teachers working in my university.

Now i would like to create a link between the Teacher instance and the Course, so while i'm creating a new course i will have the list of ALL teachers in the university and i can chose one (or more) from this list.

How can i do that, should i define this list of teachers while i'm registering the taxonomy **Teacher**? Can you give me some code snippet to create this kind of association?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something similar to what you want to do is found on the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). Their example is books by genre and writer.